# Python2.7 - Sqlite3 - 2 inputs

Tags: python, sqlite

I am writing a small python script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
from sys import argv,exit

db_name = "hashez.db"

def define_db():
    try:
        conn = sqlite.connect(db_name)
    except IOError as e:
        print "problem while creating/connecting the db:",e.args[0]
        exit(1)

    return conn

def write_db(conn,cursor,na,ha):
    conn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (name TEXT UNIQUE, hash TEXT UNIQUE)")
    query = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO user VALUES($name,$hash)"
    cursor.execute(query,[na],[ha])
    cursor.close()  
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(argv) == 2:
        na,ha = argv[1]
        #ha = argv[2]
    else:
        print "no argument given - stopping now"
        exit(1)

    conn = define_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    write_db(conn,cursor,na,ha)
```

I have no problem when I try to take in one input

`python user.py blah`

but When I try to do with more than one,It goes into the else loop.

where am I doing the errors? Please guide me thru...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because the first argument is actually the file name.

A simple test file shows how this works:

```
[~]$ cat test.py
from sys import argv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print argv
    print len(argv)
[~]$ python test.py one two
['test.py', 'one', 'two']
3
[~]$ python test.py one
['test.py', 'one']
2
```

You should also fix your SQL/query

```
query = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO user VALUES(?,?)"
cursor.execute(query,[na,ha])
conn.commit()
```

See the [sqlite api docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html).

Answer (score 0):

The first element in `sys.argv` is the name of the script, so you probably actually want the following for your if statement:

```
if len(argv) == 3:
    na = argv[1]
    ha = argv[2]
```

Comment: But, If I understand it correctly, `len(argv)` can't go beyond `2`? or

EDIT:

NO, I AM WRONG!